# How can I book the interrail passholder Eurostar fare?

Tags: europe, trains, interrail, eurostar

I don't see an option for it online. I'm in Sweden. Do I need to wait until I get to Paris to make a reservation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a lot of handy info on the [Seat61.com InterRail Pass page](http://www.seat61.com/InterRail-pass-guide.htm#How%20does%20an%20InterRail%20pass%20work) about this. Interestingly, much of it isn't positive about the InterRail discounted tickets...

A couple of key bits to pull out (but you'll really want to go and read the whole thing!)

> Eurostar isn't covered ....  The best and cheapest option is usually to forget your pass and buy a regular cheap Eurostar ticket well in advance at www.eurostar.com.  These start from just £39 one way or £69 return .....
>
> In theory, Eurostar offers a 'special' fare for InterRail passholders, £57 one way, £100 return, with changes to travel plans allowed, but as you can see, this is actually more expensive than the cheapest regular fare if you book a month or two in advance and commit to a specific date and train ......
>
> but be warned, the number of passholder tickets is controlled by a quota and people have turned up at the station on a Sunday to be told there are no passholder places available on any Eurostar departure until Wednesday, and if they wanted to travel immediately they'd have to pay the full-price regular fare, a whopping £170 for immediate departure ......
>
> Alternatively, take a ferry to mainland Europe:  If you prefer to travel by ferry rather than Eurostar, or if you find all the cheap Eurostar fares sold out, there are several cheap ferry options.
>
> Top tip:  South Eastern Trains offer a £33.90 day trip ticket from London to Calais covering both train and ferry, which is cheaper even for a one-way trip than a £34 train ticket to Dover and a £30 ferry ticket on to Calais

So, assuming you don't just end up buying a normal cheap Eurostar ticket, and you don't decide on using the return half of a London-Calais day return by ferry

If you did want to book, then the [InterRail website says](http://www.interrailnet.com/support/plan-trip/interrail-pass-valid-on-eurostar) that you can't book pass holder fares online. Instead, your options are to book by phone on +44 (0) 1233 617 575 (and I believe pay a fiver booking fee), or buy the ticket at a Eurostar terminal and hope that there are still some passholder fares left (otherwise it's going to get expensive!)

Comment: The normal price Eurostar tickets for the dates I want are alreaady at over £130, so yeah it makes sense for me to buy the passholder rate. Thanks for the no. I'll give them a call

Comment: I called them and booked, and it was like.. £2 cheaper than the regular fare. What a bargain. I guess I do get a free change included in it, but since my travel plans are pretty set it is worthless to me. Going to the UK with an Interrail pass is almost not even worth it.

Comment: You probably would have been better off on the ferry! Or book earlier next time...

Comment: The ferry takes far too long. I guess you pay for convenience.

Comment: I would also suggest to book directly in a Swedish station. When  I used an Interrail pass, I booked a train abroad in my own country without any problem. I guess it depends on the countries, but it's worth trying. And the Eurostar pricing is closer to flight pricing than train pricing in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Quite a few things have now changed since the original answer was written in 2011 so to update for 2022.

Interrail reservations are available online through https://www.b-europe.com/EN/Booking/Pass#TravelWish - if you are traveling with a mobile pass you'll need to generate a pass cover number using [for Eurail](https://www.eurail.com/en/book-reservations#/generatePassCoverNumber) or [for Interrail](https://www.interrail.eu/en/book-reservations#/generatePassCoverNumber) passes.

You can also get reservations through the Interrail reservation service: https://www.interrail.eu/en/book-reservations#/

They can also be purchased in person at any of railway stations served by Eurostar. Or from SBB railway station ticket offices in Switzerland. This is detailed at: https://www.interrail.eu/en/plan-your-trip/tips-and-tricks/trains-europe/high-speed-trains/eurostar

Reservations in standard class cost €30 except for journeys to/from the Netherlands which cost €35. Some of the above channels do add an extra booking fee on. There is a limited quota of interrail reservations available so it is possible for them to sell out even though there are still full priced standard tickets on sale.

Comment: tip: consider journeys other than the most obvious ones. I travelled to Marseille from greater manchester on an interrail and was unable to get any reservations from London to Paris, but I *was* able to get reservations from London to Lille and Lille to Marseille.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answers:

general booking information on interrail/eurail is found at https://www.interrail.eu/en/book-reservations#/

they offer some special products (1 adult, economy), at the time of writing. The cheapest are

- [4 days within 1 month](https://www.interrail.eu/en/interrail-passes/global-pass), 246€
- [Travel in 2 or more countries](https://www.interrail.eu/en/interrail-passes/global-pass), 335€

If you prefer to travel 1st class, above products are a quite more expensive (add about an extra 33%)

- 4 days within 1 month, 328€
- Travel in 2 or more countries, 446€

add to those rates the [Seat Reservation](https://www.interrail.eu/en/book-reservations#/) fee, which you mandatory need to book on high-speed/night trains.